# Showing Document content in a Responsive manner in my android app

Tags: android, text, responsive-design

I am currently working with a content showing app for which  I have bunch of datas and I have to arrange them and show in my app such that that content feel like mobile friendly(Actually I tried to show the pdf document directly with a github library but that resulted in a non-responsive show Like 'Desktop sites' shows in mobile..
What Can I do or approach to solve my problem?

For example I have a document like..[image]

**Now if I want to show that document directly in my app it is not at all mobile friendly..But no-one wants an app to show non-responsive texts..
So, what should be done that I have a responsive view of my content..**

**SO I AM ASKING WHAT IS THE WAY TO SHOW THIS NON-RESPONSIVE DOCUMENT CONTENTS IN A MOBILE FRIENDLY MANNER**

Comment: Please feel free to give any suggestion before closing it with downvotes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out the simplest solution..Just convert the document to html using MS Word `save as webpage` option..It produces responsive html and then show it in the webview ..It is the simplest and most economic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you can do is to use those PDF documents as images. Then you can add them to drawables in your resources folder. After which you can insert the documents as images in your project instead of non responsive text.